# Determining if a Number N can be written as sum of one or more numbers from 1,2.....K each used at most once?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How to determine if a natural number N can be written as sum of numbers from 1,2...K such that each number 1,2,3...K is used at most once( ie a number can be used one or 0 times)

Also we need to determinine ,the minimum number of numbers required to form N

Answer (score 1):

If $N\leq\dfrac{K(K+1)}{2}$ it is possible.

Proof:
Induction on K

If K=1, it is true.
Let's assume it is true for all natural numbers less than K. We can represent  $\dfrac{K(K+1)}{2},\dfrac{K(K+1)}{2}-1,\dfrac{K(K+1)}{2}-2,....\dfrac{K(K+1)}{2}-(K-1)$ by adding all except one number(and all numbers in the first case). All the smaller numbers can be represented by $1,2,3..K-1$ So, it's true for all $K\in \mathbb{N}$

For Part 2 Let's try the Greedy algorithm. First add K, (If it's not  bigger than N.) then try K-1 , K-2 and so on. There is clearly a solution in this form(Using the above result) and also it's the optimum one. I'm not sure how to find a closed form for the size though.

I'm guessing that the number $l$(the number of numbers required) is such that $\sum _{i=K-l+1}^Ki\geq N$ and l is the minimum l satisfying.

Proof:
If $N\leq K$ this works. If not add K to the sum and try with N-K, if $N-K\leq K-1$ we can us e the former argument and so on(This eventually terminates). I think it's inductively provable.
 So, we do have a closed form as we can then  solve $\sum _{i=K-l+1}^Ki= N$ and take the integer next to it.

Comment: @Also,I need to find the minimum number of number from 1 to K required to form N

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the proof of Ishan Banerjee.

Clearly you need
$$
N \le \frac{K (K+1)}{2},\tag{cond}
$$
as $\dfrac{K (K+1)}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{K} i$.

Now assume (cond), and proceed by induction on $K$, the cases $K = 1, 2$ begin clear.

So suppose $K > 2$, and assume by induction  to be able to deal with
$$
N \le \frac{K (K-1)}{2}.
$$
So suppose
$$
\frac{K (K-1)}{2} < N \le \frac{K (K+1)}{2}.
$$
Since $K \ge 3$, we have $1 \le (K-1)/2$ so that $K \le \dfrac{K (K-1)}{2} < N$. Thus
$$
0 \le N - K \le \frac{K (K+1)}{2} - K = \frac{K (K-1)}{2},
$$
and induction applies.

Comment: @Also,I need to find the minimum number of number from 1 to K required to form N

Answer (score 0):

My answer: Consider $g(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3) \dots$

The coefficient of $x^N$ is the number of ways $N$ can be written as the sum of distinct natural numbers.

Comment: OK, but what does this have to do with the questions being asked here?

Comment: When multiplying to obtain the term in x^N, you are adding distinct natural numbers in the index!

Comment: I know, thanks, but have you read the questions asked by OP?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: you are right,he doesn't seem to have read or understood the question properly.